# How to set configuration options for particular sub blogs?

Tags: multisite

Is it possible to set configuration options such as DEBUG mode only for specific sub blogs in a wordpress multisite installation? If so, how?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Hi **@Raj Sekharan:**

If I understand your question lets say you have three (3) subdomains on your multisite and you only want to debug the first?

1. http://foo.example.com
2. http://bar.example.com
3. http://baz.example.com

If yes then it's a simply matter of adding the following to your `/wp-config.php` file:

```
if ($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']=='foo.example.com')
  define('WP_DEBUG', true);
else 
  define('WP_DEBUG', false);
```

Or if you are a fan of terse coding you can just do it like this:

```
define('WP_DEBUG', $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']=='foo.example.com');
```

Comment: man.. do I feel dumb. :P 

one more time! mike rocks! :)

Comment: @Raj Sekharan: - Thanks, but no need to feel dumb. I can't tell you how many things I've missed only to have others point out to me *"the obvious."*  Just keep learning each time, that's all it takes! :)

Comment: perfect tricky code :)

Answer (score -1):

If you're asking about putting that define in wp-config and making it apply to one site, then no.

Comment: Sure, it is possible. Take a look at `$_REQUEST` and `$_SERVER`  - then go with conditional `if/else`.