# How to individually set WP_DEBUG on a sub-directory multisite?

Tags: multisite, directory, wp-config, wp-debug

According to [this question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/6712/how-to-set-configuration-options-for-particular-sub-blogs), it's possible to turn on/off `WP_DEBUG` for specific sites on a multisite.

Is it possible to do this with a **sub-directory multisite**?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this by adding some code to wp-config.php

```
$request_uri = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$debug_dirs = array ('/debug-dir1/','/debug-dir2/'); // list of directories to turn on debugging
foreach ($debug_dirs as $debug_dir) {
    if (!strncmp($request_uri,$debug_dir,strlen($debug_dir))) {
        define('WP_DEBUG', true);
    } 
}
define('WP_DEBUG', false); // debug off by default
```

Comment: doesn't work for me (WP 3.8.1). maybe it's because the debug_dirs only exist virtually through permalinks and aren't actual folders!?

Comment: Sorry, I had it working and then changed it when I pasted the code in here.  The problem is that defining WP_DEBUG should only happen once.  The default WP_DEBUG setting (false) has to happen at the very end and not the beginning!

Answer (score 0):

Here is what worked for me

```
$url = 'http://' . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
if (strpos($url,'sitename') !== false) {
            define('WP_DEBUG', true);
}
```